# Why is $regex in $lookup through $addFields result not working in mongodb aggregation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have `groups` and `students` collections.

```
Groups: {_id : ObjectId, title: String}
Students{mainGroups: String}
```

`mainGroups` is a concatenated string, for all `groups`, every student has taken in school.

My code is giving me, all `students` collection for all `groups`.

I want to aggregate the `groups` collection with `students` and get the `students` collection as a single array, for every `groups`, with however many `students` are returned.

```
[
  //mainGroups is String that`s why I convert Group`s $_id to String here
  {$addFields: {
    gid: {$toString:"$_id"}  
  }},
  {$project: {
     _id: 1,
     gid: 1,
     title:1
  }},
  { 
   $lookup: {
    "from": 'students',
    "let": {"groupId": "$gid"},
    pipeline: [
      {"$match": 
        {"$expr" :  
          {"mainGroups":{"$regex": "$$groupId", "$options" :"i"}}
        }
      }
    ],
    as: "student"
   }
  },
]
```

How can I get the number of `students` for every `groups`?

Comment: Wouldn't an array of `"_id"`s be preferable for `"groups"` in the `Students` collection documents, rather than a concatenated string?  You could then use a multikey index that would increase performance.  It also seems like _false matches_ might occur when _straddling_ concatenated `"id"` values.

Comment: it should, but I added in this 'mainGroups' field price of course along with groupId. Like this: groupId-priceOfCourse. Ex: 'groupId1-2500,groupId2-3000,groupId3-1000'